# Change default file type to ALL in save file dialog

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, files

Is there a way to force the file save dialog to always show `ALL` file types without having to select it from the drop down list of file types in the bottom right corner of the dialog.

For example, I attempt to save a file with .jpg from a web browser, the save dialog opens and only shows files with this extension and the file type drop down is fixed at .jpg and I cannot see any other file types, even .jpeg unless I switch it to All files.

When doing a lot of repetitive work, this gets a but frustrating

I would prefer initially viewing ALL file types always by default and if I prefer to see only files of a certain type I will choose it from the drop down.

The default behavior is the exact opposite of my preference and use cases.

Comment: Highly relevant. I am afraid it is not easily possible. It is the application that sets that while calling the file dialogs.

Comment: Ah, so an example would be the chromium browser is telling nautilus specifically to limit the dialog by file type of said file type being downloaded (saved) and this is baked in behavior one cannot modify.  Thanks for clarifying.

I also searched for a kb shortcut but came up empty.  One can toggle hidden files using a kb shortcut but it appears not the current file type filter.

Comment: It is indeed one of the parameters in a call of the application to the GTK dialog (or the program's own dialog or Qt dialogs for Qt programs...) (not nautilus). I am not aware of shortcuts. Keyboard support tends to be more and more sloppy.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarity.  I also tried pressing tab to see if that could be an alternative, i.e. press tab X no of times and then A for all files + carriage return but the save dialog tabs through all options "except" this one only.  Go fig.  Not sure what to do with this question, just leave it open to see if one day it is solved?